# regex for the following language

Tags: regex

strings over the alphabet{a,b,c,d} where no `b` is immediately followed by an `a` and no `c` is immediately by a `d`.

This is what I came up with and it fails for some of the cases.
Can you please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
a*(a|d)*(b(c|d|b)+)*(c(a|b|c)+)*(d(a|b|c|d)+)*
```

Comment: This sounds like a Computer Science question, making it more appropriate for [cstheory.se].  In any case, the `nsregularexpression` tag applies to the class of that name in Objective-C, so I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple using a negative look-ahead:

```
^(?!.*(ba|cd))[a-d]*
```

Explanation:

- `(ba|cd)` means *either* `ba` or `cd`
- `^(?!.*(ba|cd))` means looking ahead (without consuming) from the start (`^`), there should **not** be, anywhere in the input (`.*`), either `ba` or `cd`
- `[a-d]*` means any number of only of a,b,c or d

Comment: This cuts off after it comes to an invalid character, not a negative, just a feature

Comment: @AramKocharyan I think you need the `^` anchor and the `.*` in the look ahead, otherwise it matches `baabc` (when the scanner is past `ba` at `ba|abc`) but it should not match. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of your sub expressions look like this:

```
(c(a|b|c)+)
```

This says that "a c that must be followed by one of {a,b,c}. You are trying to say "a c cannot be followed by a d",  But this is not actually one of the rules.  This expression does not allow just a singe "c" which should be accepted.

Another problem with this sub expression is that it might pair a `c` with a `c`.   This expression matches "cc",  the expression that follows this expression is `(d(a|b|c|d)+)*` which would match "dc", so the string "ccdc" is matched by these two expressions, which gives us a `d` following a `c`, which is against the rules.

So ask yourself.  What is really ok to follow a `c`?  is it okay if a `d` follows a `c`?  obviously not.  is it ok if an `a` follows a `c`?  yes.  Is it ok if a `b` follows a c?  yes.  So we are tempted to write `c(b|a)`.   but does a `c` HAVE to be followed be one of these?  no.  so lets try `c(b|a)*`.  However as we see from above, we probably don't want our regex to "eat" the `b`, since once we have a `b`, we have to worry if the letter following the `b` is an a or not.  So the best we can do here is `ca*`

Follow the same logic to figure out an expression for things staring with `b`.  You come up with `bd*`

these should be able to be repeated, so we get `(ca*|bd*)*`.  How does this read?  "A `c` can be followed by `a`s.  A `b` can be followed by `d`s.  This still doesn't get us all the way.  We want to make sure tha
t a `d` doesn't immediately follow a `c`.  but all we have allowed for is for a `d` to follow `b`.  We fail since "cad" isn't accepted by our regex.  once we have seen the `a` after the `c`, the `d` is ok.   So instead of `ca*`, we need an expression that says "after a `ca` then any combination of `a` and `d` is allowed.   Since this is homework, I don't give the full expression.  If you are still following along, you should be able to figure it out.

We are most of the way there.  The only thing left is to realize that we don't care how many `a`s and `d`s come at the beginning of the string before we see our first `b` or `c`.  But the final regex will have the form "`a`s and `d`s are ok at the beginning of the string.  Then we have a repeating section of "if I see a `b` or `c` i need to worry about what comes next...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will give it to you.  If you're not allowed the `?` operator, just replace it with the `*`.

This allows for `a` or `d` followed by anything; `b` followed by `b,c,d` or terminating the string, and `c` followed by `b,c,d` or terminating the string.

```
    (a|d|(b+(c|d))|(c+(b|d)))*(b|c)*
```

Comment: that has more open parens than close parens.

Comment: Egads.  Why did I even answer this question.  Fixed for the last time.  Changed the last clause to `*`, though equivalently it could have been changed to allow `b` back into the choice after the `b+` (and similarly for `c`).

Answer (score 0):

What I got:

```
(a|b(?!a)|c(?!d)|d)+
```

To test:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: What about the empty string, abc, acb?  Does b[^a] require that there be two characters from the language?

Comment: It fails on `dca` and also accepts `dce`, even though it can only support `[abcd]`

Comment: @dabble125, Yeah, you were right. I switched to negative lookaheads instead.

Comment: @AramKocharyan, Without more context, I don't know if he means to match a string in a larger string of text, or a single string against the pattern. I figured that he can start of string and end of string matchers as needed.

Comment: I got the idea that {a,b,c,d} was the set of all valid characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<!b)a|(?<!c)d|b(?!a)|c(?!d)
```

It ensures that no `a` follows a `b` and that no `b` has an `a` in front of it. It ensures that no `d` follows a `c` and that no `c` has a `d` in front of it.

Also, I'd wrap that in a `()` if you were going to add anything else to it.

Comment: No it doesn't... It matches any c that doesn't have a d in front

Answer (score 0):

```
(a|b(?!a)|c(?!d)|d)+
```

This works....but how would I made that...without the ? or the !

it seems to fail which ever way i do it...im begining to doubt its even a regular expression